# Passing object as parameters to wcf web service function

Tags: php, web-services, wcf

I am consuming WCF web service in php and need to pass the parameters to the function of the webservice. The xml request looks like as fetched from SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <tem:Display>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:req>
             <!-- Here are parameters -->
         </tem:req>
       </tem:Display>
<soapenv:Body>
```

How to pass parameters in this condition?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use header('Content-type: text/xml') on starting the xml body, see example below and try in your code:

Answer (score 0):

if our parameters are passed as an array as:

```
$parameters = array('param1' => 'value1', 'param2'=> 'value2');
```

for above request we need nesting as:

```
$parameters = array(
        'req' => array('param1' => 'value1', 'param2'=> 'value2')
         );
```

this is how we pass objects as parameters.